# How far can blood spray?

Tags: creature-design, blood

A creature has evolved to protect the herd. Its blood contains chemicals that act like pepper spray, burning the eyes and throat of anything around it. However it wants to be able to get a decent coverage on a pack of predators.

**So how large an area could the blood be sprayed into?**

To clarify I'm picturing a weaker member of the herd being caught - perhaps a younger one - and when the predator's bite severs an artery the blood is released.

I suppose, really, the question can be interpreted as "How high a blood pressure is possible?"

Another few points:

- Gravity: Similar to ours
- Animals, same basic structure - hearts pumping blood around and such.

Comment: I wonder how such an effect might evolve... After all, being torn asunder by predators is not exactly something that gives you an advantage in mating...

Comment: Neither does menopause. Evolution is about passing genes. Genes don't care if it;s you or your sister that has off spring. Mostly I don't understand how predators would eat such animals at all. They either evolve immunite or avoid them entirely. You can't eat 'around' the blood.

Comment: Have you heard of the [horned lizard](https://asknature.org/strategy/eyes-squirt-blood/)?

Comment: So if the animal gets hurt by a non-predator, it still explodes, spraying the other members of its herd? Maybe you should make this voluntary. I'm btw not saying this is a bad question, I'm just curious because I like weird things

Comment: @Burki Imagine two herds, one has this mutation and the other doesn't. The herd with this loses one of their weakest and the rest of the predators are unable to keep up the chase. The other herd gets chased down and loses more members...and so is weaker.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Yeah, well I wasn't imagining it as an attack and I didn't really want it to be anything noble (like maybe the alpha of the herd would actually weaken competitors or some such specifically so they can get eaten as a sacrifice). But it does effect the herd itself once the blood is released (in the story an early intelligent species uses bows and arrows to kill one of these animals whilst they're in the herd and the blood in incapacitates other members which makes them easier targets for traps and more arrows).

Comment: Look at blood pressure in geraffes.

Comment: @Draco18s That is pretty cool...and gross...

Comment: If no one else gets around to it I will answer later.  But like @JDługosz mentioned I think the answer here would be to figure out bp in a larger mammal (elephants perhaps) and then to the math based on blood vessel diameter.  There wouldn't be a *standard* distance as predator bites aren't nice clean cuts but we can get a general idea...and this is a crazy and awesome defense mechanism for the record...

Comment: You should look at the [Camponotus saundersi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camponotus_saundersi), a type of ant that can violently explode when it deems itself to be in a situation that it can't possibly survive. By contracting a few muscles in it's body it can make two oversized glands just behind his head explode and spray a sort of glue on all enemies around it. The glue is also a chemical irritant and helps immobilize nearby enemies.

Comment: Does it really have to be blood? As already pointed out by callosaurus, skunks come pretty close to what you describe, but they live to tell the tale...

Comment: How would a predator even eat something with blood like that?  Bites of meat contain blood.  Maybe the predator would stash the kill under a log to ferment for a few days.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right that blood pressure can be used as a proxy for how far it could potentially be sprayed. Knowing that healthy human blood pressure should peak at around 120mmHg, and bottom out at 80mmHg, it can spurt [around 15 cm vertically and 46cm laterally](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,748742,00.html).

The giraffe has one of the [highest recorded blood pressures](https://bpsfuelforthought.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/why-giraffes-dont-have-brain-damage/) in the animal kingdom at 240/180mmHg due to a host of cool physiological features, so you could loosely double the spurt range from an artery to 30cm vertically and 100cm laterally.

However, animals make use of other liquid projectiles:

- [Skunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunk#Anal_scent_glands) can accurately spray secretions from muscled anal glands with a high degree of accuracy as far as 300cm (which can cause irritation and even temporary blindness).
- Bombardier beetles rapid-fire [superheated benzoquinone](http://news.mit.edu/2015/how-bombardier-beetles-produce-defensive-spray-0430) [quite accurately](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC22274/) up to [20cm](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/04/080401170543.htm).
- The [spitting cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitting_cobra) can spit venom from its hollow front fangs [up to 150cm](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/notrocketscience/2010/05/14/how-spitting-cobras-shoot-for-the-eyes/#more-1611) at a victim's eyes.
- Southern [giant petrels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_giant_petrel) can defensively squirt stomach oils up to [100-200 cm](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/tetrapod-zoology/living-pelagic-life-petrels-part-ii/).

Projectile use isn't common in the animal kingdom because of the energetic constraints of making the projectiles, [but certainly has evolved before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_use_by_animals).

Every mammal can, of course, urinate (larger animals have [higher flow speed](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/33/11932.full.pdf) and, I would assume, greater effective range) to excrete soluble wastes and mark territory. You could invent some interesting defence given that urinating in the face of danger is common to all animals, [including humans](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28578/why-do-we-urinate-more-when-we-are-nervous), but the toxicity of urine is probably dependent on what is consumed in the first place.

Comment: I like the fiery pee idea...

Comment: human blood pressure during exercise (such as running from a big predator) can spike to 200 mm Hg or higher.

Comment: I should have clarified the blood pressures to be 'at rest'. I would assume the blood pressure of a giraffe also increases substantially when running away. (New event at the morbid olympics: Long Spurt?)

Comment: Even at rest I would guess it gives me an order of magnitude idea, right? Like 100cm for giraffe at rest isn't going to turn into 1000cm for him running is it?. I'm still sticking with the blood idea for story reasons but thanks for the others.

Comment: It does. I doubt you could find 10 metres naturally. Bonus reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autohaemorrhaging
You could have some sort of specialized 'appendage' on the rear of the animal (or wherever is most likely to get snagged by a predator's claws) that swells massively with a certain finite volume of blood during escape, and if snagged begins to dislodge its contents. This may be difficult because predators would eventually learn of, and plan around, the blood-hose and only attack from a different angle.

Comment: During afterbirth it is possible to squirt blood at least 5 meters. Humans are the clear winner here :D

Answer (score 10):

The [Horned Lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horned_lizard) already does this after a fashion.

> ...are also able to squirt an aimed stream of blood from the corners
>   of the eyes for a distance of up to 5 feet (1.5 m).

This is a single target squirt, not an area effect but nature has already found a solution that you can use as a model.

The main thing is that they pressurize the blood in the head to increase the range of the squirt.

If you are using simple blood pressure to provide the spray, you are inviting a bleed out situation any time they are injured.  It might be better to have blood accumulate in "pressure vessels" or "blood sacks" under the skin that can be closed off when they lose pressure to prevent too much blood loss.

It could also have specially designed pores leading to those sacks.  If the sacks collect blood waste products, the blood could be mildly toxic or irritating then.  You could use the [Cane Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_toad) of Australia as an example.  They don't really squirt (it is more like ooze) but there's no reason your critter can't use a similar mechanism under pressure.